# How to see complete process name that is running using prstat command on solaris

Tags: solaris

I am running command "prstat -v" on Solaris but it is showing very short process name as below: (see last column values under PROCESS/NLWP). Which option in prstat gives me complete process name that is running?

```
 PID USERNAME USR SYS TRP TFL DFL LCK SLP LAT VCX ICX SCL SIG PROCESS/NLWP

  2709 root     0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 100 0.0   0   0   0   0 sshd/1

  2624 root     0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0  50  50 0.0   0   0   0   0 in.rarpd/3

  2648 root     0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 100 0.0   0   0   0   0 sendmail/1

 24429 root     0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0  98 2.5 0.0   1   0   1   0 java/807
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to fall back on other utilities to get full process names.

For example:

```
$ pargs -l $$
/usr/bin/bash
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any way to do that.

Answer (score 0):

`prstat` on its own will not give you what you want. However if you use `ps` and `awk` you can often get enough. For example to check on the rss values for each process I use the command

```
ps -ef -o rss -o args |  awk '{ hr=$1/1024 ; printf("%13.6f Mb ",hr) } { for ( x=2 ; x<=NF ; x++ ) { printf("%s ",$x) } print "" }' | sort -n -r
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use the 'ww' argument with the bsd ps:

```
# /usr/ucb/ps -aguxww 
root      1177  0.0  0.0    0    0 ?        S   Dec 13  0:00 zsched
root      1189  0.0  0.1 1868 1260 ?        S   Dec 13  0:00 /sbin/init
root      1208  0.0  0.211072 9144 ?        S   Dec 13  0:04 /lib/svc/bin/svc.startd
root      1239  0.0  0.21308811908 ?        S   Dec 13  0:18 /lib/svc/bin/svc.configd
root      1326  0.0  0.0 1592  852 ?        S   Dec 13  0:00 /sbin/sh /lib/svc/method/svc-dlmgmtd
root      1538  0.0  0.1 6972 4216 ?        S   Dec 13  0:30 /usr/sbin/nscd
root      1886  0.0  0.1 1956 1248 ?        S   Dec 13  0:00 /usr/sbin/cron
root      2045  0.0  0.1 2296 1312 ?        S   Dec 13  0:00 /usr/lib/saf/sac -t 300
root      2082  0.0  0.1 2476 1408 ?        S   Dec 13  0:00 /usr/lib/saf/ttymon
root      2118  0.0  0.1 3824 1764 ?        S   Dec 13  0:03 /usr/sbin/syslogd
root      2119  0.0  0.0 1572  844 ?        S   Dec 13  0:00 /usr/lib/utmpd
root      2132  0.0  0.1 6112 3468 ?        S   Dec 13  0:39 /usr/lib/inet/inetd start
root      2222  0.0  0.1 1872 1304 console  S   Dec 13  0:00 /usr/lib/saf/ttymon -g -d /dev/console -l console -m ldterm,ttcompat -h -p mail
root      2257  0.0  0.1 4124 1788 ?        S   Dec 13  0:00 /usr/lib/ssh/sshd
root      2489  0.0  0.1 2280 1324 ?        S   Dec 13  0:00 /usr/sadm/lib/smc/bin/smcboot
root      2491  0.0  0.0 2280  980 ?        S   Dec 13  0:00 /usr/sadm/lib/smc/bin/smcboot
root      2539  0.0  0.0 2280  976 ?        S   Dec 13  0:00 /usr/sadm/lib/smc/bin/smcboot
root      2854  0.0  0.1 5936 2620 ?        S   Dec 13  0:07 /usr/lib/sendmail -bl -q15m
root      3277  0.0  0.1 7784 2096 ?        S   Dec 13  0:00 /usr/dt/bin/dtlogin -daemon -udpPort 0
root     13216  0.0  0.1 6944 4188 ?        S   Dec 15  0:00 /usr/lib/ssh/sshd
root     13245  0.0  0.1 6944 4188 ?        S   Dec 15  0:00 /usr/lib/ssh/sshd
root     27680  0.0  0.0 1504  892 ?        S 12:35:21  0:00 sleep 3600
root     28311  0.0  0.1 6944 4220 ?        S 12:59:01  0:00 /usr/lib/ssh/sshd
#
```